# How do I add /home to arch with uuid if I messed up while installing?

Tags: arch-linux, home, uuid

I installed arch Linux but I forgot to make my desired home partition. /home. I accidentally forgot to change the partition from Linux filesystem to add /home. I changed the partition to /home after installation and setup of Gnome. I want to make it auto mount by use of uuid. All my drives are GPT. I've had to do this in Ubuntu before but when I changed Swap size. I no longer remember how I did that and this is my first installation of Arch. I have set up two drives for my system. A 120GB SSD as well as a 1TB HDD.

My partitions are as follows:

SSD 120GB
/dev/sda1 524MB BIOS Boot

/dev/sda2 472MB Linux Filesystem Ext2

/dev/sda3 119GB Linux filesystem Ext4 / (root)

HDD 1TB
/dev/sdb1 989 GB Ext4 /home
/dev/sdb2 11GB SWAP

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run `blkid` to find out the UUID of the relevant partition, then edit `/etc/fstab` accordingly.

Comment: I actually figured it out a bit before I got this message

Comment: @Sato I think you should put that as an answer so I can make the question answered. So it could be of some help to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `blkid` to find out the UUID of the relevant partition, then edit `/etc/fstab` accordingly:

```
UUID=...    /home    ext4    nosuid,nodev,noatime    1 2
```